# Oracle where clause condition not executing with subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as follows: Column c has a case statement for case 'P' and case 'M'.
The condition inside case 'P' is not working-> "and cs.case_id not in (SELECT case_id FROM case_status where (case_status_id = 16 and case_status_date < sysdate - 365)) AND cs.case_status_id = lk.id".
case Status for P is one to many so it's in a different table and for 'M' it's one to one so it's in the same cases table.
Also case status 'P' may or may not have record for a case.

```
SELECT 
        c.case_id,
        c.id id,
        lkp_alt.descr AS name,
        (CASE WHEN c.case_type = 'P' THEN
                   (SELECT listagg(lk.descr, ', ') AS status
                      FROM case_status      cs,
                           lkp_case_status  lk
                     WHERE c.case_id = cs.case_id 
                       and cs.case_id not in (SELECT case_id
                                                FROM case_status
                                               where (case_status_id = 16 
                                                      and case_status_date < sysdate - 365)
                                             )  
                       AND cs.case_status_id = lk.id
                     GROUP BY c.case_id
                   )
              ELSE (SELECT listagg(status, ', ') AS status
                      FROM (SELECT case_id,
                                   lk.descr AS status
                              FROM lkp_hqmc_case_status lk
                             WHERE c.case_type = 'M' 
                               AND lk.id = c.hamc_case_status
                             UNION
                            SELECT c.case_id,
                                   lk.descr AS status
                              FROM lkp_fl_case_status lk
                             WHERE c.case_type = 'M' 
                               AND lk.id = c.fl_case_status
                            )
                      GROUP BY case_id
                   )
            END
        ) AS status
  from cases  c,
       lkp_alt_show_cause_authority  lkp_alt
 WHERE c.ascAt = lkp_alt.id(+)
   AND c.delete_date IS NULL
   and not (nvl(c.hamc_case_status,0) = 8 
                   and c.CLOSE_DATE < sysdate - 365
                  )  
 ORDER BY c.case_id desc
```

Case Table

```
id  name   hamc_case_status  case_type 
1   AAA    1                 P
2   BBB    1                P
3   CCC     1                P
4   DDD     1               P
```

case_status

```
1   16 01-NOV-19 03.42.37.420000000 PM
1   5 01-NOV-19 03.42.37.420000000 PM
2   1  18-NOV-19 12.36.11.268000000 PM
2   3  18-NOV-19 12.36.11.268000000 PM
3   5  18-NOV-21 12.36.11.268000000 PM
3   16 18-NOV-21 12.36.11.268000000 PM

lkp_alt_show_cause_authority  

id desc
1   TEST
2   TEST1

lkp_hqmc_case_status 
id descr
1  status
2  status1..
8  Closed

lkp_fl_case_status
id descr
1  fstatus1
2  fstatus2

lkp_case_status
id Descr
1  Active
2  Intermediate
3  InActive
5  Prep
16 Closed
```

The output should show as follows:
Result:

```
id name status
2   BBB Active, InActive
3   CCC Prep, Closed
4   DDD
```

It shouldnt pull case with id = 1 since the case closed status 16 is in '01-NOV-19'
Output I get with this query is:

```
id name status
1   null
2   BBB Active, InActive
3   CCC Prep, Closed
4   DDD
```

It is a legacy application with 150 fields and multiple joins on reporting. I cannot change query with 'outer join'.
I have to use same format of tablea, tableb and use (+) for joins.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you are missing some sample tables/data to help troubleshoot the query. You have provided data for `CASES` and `CASE_STATUS` but the query also uses `lkp_case_status`, `lkp_hqmc_case_status`, `lkp_fl_case_status`, and `lkp_alt_show_cause_authority`

Comment: @ EJ i have added as requested

Comment: `not (nvl(c.hamc_case_status,0) = 8 
                   and c.CLOSE_DATE < sysdate - 365
                  )`  is evaluate as `TRUE` when `c.hamc_case_status` is null or not  equal to 8.

Comment: @Serg I have updated case table with hamc_case_status = 1 for all records

Comment: It makes no difference. All the `cases  c` still meet your `WHERE`.  Correct it as needed to exclude the row. Note  a `CASE` in a `SELECT` list doesn't affect the set of rows selected.

Comment: @Serg case id 1, with case status 16 and date '01-NOV-19 03.42.37.420000000 PM', doesnt meet the inner select condition. So case with id = 1 has to be excluded

Comment: Don't get it. What is the "inner select condition" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241580/discussion-between-jnpw-and-serg).